# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Tags: python, list, nan

I have one list with different lines. Each line has many different numbers inside the column "Value". Below I put to you a little example. Overall there are 67 elements within the variable "objects". You can see there are numbers and "nan". I would like to replace these "nan" with "0".
I have already tried different types of scripts.
[image]

Below there is one script (many times I tried it), but I always receive mistakes or I don't have the replace with zero.

```
objects.fillna(0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

Also I have tried with "replace", below there is the script and error.

```
lists = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('nan', '0'), objects))
print(lists)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

To help, below there is the script for creating "objects". I am trying the script of this site [click here](https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/python-geographic-object-based-image-analysis-geobia/).

```
objects = []
object_ids = []
for id in segment_ids:
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    object_features = segment_features(segment_pixels)
    objects.append(object_features)
    object_ids.append(id)
```

Comment: Show the code that created `objects` valuable as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `fillna` and `replace` are methods you can use on `pandas.DataFrame` or `pandas.Series`, not on a `list`.

If the lists in `objects` have all the same length you can easily convert it into a `DataFrame`, fillna and convert it back to a list

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(objects)
df = df.fillna(0)
objects = df.to_numpy().tolist()
```

If they have different lengths you can convert each list into a `Series`, fillna and convert them back to a list

```py
import pandas as pd

row_func = lambda x: pd.Series(x).fillna(0).to_list()

objects = list(map(row_func, objects))
objects
```

Comment: A basic List comprehension is all that is required to so convert any List: `new_list = [ 0 if np.isnan(x) else x for x in old_list ]`.